# Cannot analyze XML with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have an XML file that I’m trying to analyze with Nokogiri:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<ehd:ehd ehd_version="1.40" xmlns:ehd="urn:ehd/001" xmlns="urn:ehd/icd/001">
  <ehd:header>
    <ehd:document_type_cd V="ICD" DN="ICD-Stammdatei" S="1.2.276.0.76.5.100"/>
    <ehd:service_tmr V="2013-07-01..2013-12-31"/>
  </ehd:header>
  <ehd:body>
    <icd_stammdaten>
      <kapitel_liste>
        <kapitel>
          <nummer V="1"/>
          .......
```

Normally I get an node by doing:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(params[:file])
puts doc.css('nummer')
```

Now I tried:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(params[:file])
puts doc.css('ehd:document_type_cd')
```

To get this output:

```
<ehd:document_type_cd V="ICD" DN="ICD-Stammdatei" S="1.2.276.0.76.5.100"/>
```

But somehow I get no output! How can this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **XPATH** when dealing with **XML**.

When there will be a namesapce in the XML,then the below trick using [**`Nokogiri::XML::Document#remove_namespaces!`**](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html#method-i-remove_namespaces-21) will make your life easy :

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse <<-eot
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<ehd:ehd ehd_version="1.40" xmlns:ehd="urn:ehd/001" xmlns="urn:ehd/icd/001">
  <ehd:header>
    <ehd:document_type_cd V="ICD" DN="ICD-Stammdatei" S="1.2.276.0.76.5.100"/>
    <ehd:service_tmr V="2013-07-01..2013-12-31"/>
  </ehd:header>
  eot

doc.remove_namespaces!
puts doc.at_xpath('//document_type_cd')
# >> <document_type_cd V="ICD" DN="ICD-Stammdatei" S="1.2.276.0.76.5.100"/>
```

---

Or,if you are enough good with ***namespaced*** XML,then do as below :

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse <<-eot
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<ehd:ehd ehd_version="1.40" xmlns:ehd="urn:ehd/001" xmlns="urn:ehd/icd/001">
  <ehd:header>
    <ehd:document_type_cd V="ICD" DN="ICD-Stammdatei" S="1.2.276.0.76.5.100"/>
    <ehd:service_tmr V="2013-07-01..2013-12-31"/>
  </ehd:header>
  eot

puts doc.at_xpath('//ehd:document_type_cd','document_type_cd')
# >> <ehd:document_type_cd V="ICD" DN="ICD-Stammdatei" S="1.2.276.0.76.5.100"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Nokogiri tutorial says](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html#namespaces):

> You *do not* have to use XPath to get the benefits of namespaces. CSS selectors can be used as well. CSS just uses the pipe symbol to indicate a namespace search.

So in this case you can do:

```
puts doc.css('ehd|document_type_cd')
```

if you prefer using CSS over XPath.